# Can `guard` not guards in Haskell be used to specify a particular message for `Left`

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, monads

Does the `guard` function from [RIO-Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio-0.1.22.0/docs/RIO-Prelude.html#v:guard) offer any way to decide the content of a message if it is failing an `Either`-Monad? such that e.g

```
somefun :: Either String Int
somefun =  do guard (4+2 == 8); return 2
```

would return `Left someContent` instead where the `someContent` is a string that is specified to the `guard` in some way.

I haven't been able to find any way according to the documentation, but in case it exists I would be happy to know about it, since `guard` could be a good way to avoid nested `if`-statements.

Comment: "way to decide the content of a message if it is failing an Either-Monad?" – I have almost no idea what you're talking about. Elaborate please.

Comment: @leftaroundabout , I have tried to specify with an example.

Comment: `guard` works with `emtpy` in case the condition fails, so no. You should use ``fail` instead, and thus make some `guard` that allows to add a fail message.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds more like a job for `when` or [`unless`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:unless):

```
somefun :: Either String Int
somefun = do
   unless (4+2 == 8) $ Left somecontent
   return 2
```

I'd actually rather write `when (4+2 /= 8) $ Left somecontent`.

Comment: In this context, I might be tempted to write `Left somecontent` as `throwError somecontent` to communicate the intent.

Answer (score 3):

`guard` works with `empty` in case the condition fails, so no. You should use `fail` instead, and thus make some `guard` that allows to add a fail message.

You thus can work with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance MonadFail (Either String) where
    fail = Left


guard' :: MonadFail m => String -> Bool -> m ()
guard' msg = go
  where go False = fail msg
        go True = pure ()
```

so then you fail with:

```
somefun :: Either String Int
somefun =  do guard' "arithmetic error" (4+2 == 8); return 2
```

I was actually surprised to find out `Either String` was not an instance of `MonadFail` (thanks to @JosephSible to note this).

Comment: `Either String` doesn't have a `MonadFail` instance.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: aarrggghhh, you're right. Do you know why? The only reason I can think of is that it would enable the `FlexibleInstances` pragma?

Comment: See https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/12160

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Interesting, I'm wondering whether, if eventually `IsString` will move to the standard (since `OverloadedStrings` is now quite common), they might eventually change their mind. The main point seems to be about the current state of standard Haskell, but eventually that might change.